# Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender [Spring 4.0.0 REALEASE]

Tags: spring, html-email

I tried to create a HTML mail sender in my application but i got this error. Here's my configuration using name space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/mail_server.properties" />
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then i imported it into applicationContext.xml file in Spring project. In java class i just write a method to send HTML mail.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import fi.vietjob.bean.mail.Mail;

@Repository
public class mailFeature {
    @Inject
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void getPalaute(Mail mail, String to) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        message.setText(mail.getText());
        message.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        mailSender.send(message);
    }

    public void sendHTMLEmail(Mail mail, String to, String senderName) {

        try {
            MimeMessage mime = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mime, true);
            helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom(), senderName);
            helper.setText(mail.getText());
            helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
            helper.setSentDate(new Date());
            helper.setTo(to);
            mailSender.send(mime);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And when i run it, i got the stackstrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailFeature': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender fi.vietjob.feature.mailFeature.mailSender; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you tried Autowired annotation instead of Inject annotation?

Comment: I think it is the same bro, just tried and it still not working!

Comment: Try adding `autowire="byName"` in your bean definition. And use `@Autowired`

Comment: Thanks bro i'll try and let you know it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file you created the mail sender in this way:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So spring create a bean with id `mailSender` 
When you try to inject it in your Repository, you simply use `@Inject`; try to use `@Inject` and `@Qualifier`

So try to write:

```
@Repository
public class mailFeature {
    @Inject
    @Qualifier("mailSender")
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
....
}
```

It should work

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: Thanks bro, i'll try when i comeback home from work and let you know.

Comment: It's working bro, i follow ur guide and also change JavaMailSender instead of JavaMailSenderImpl, thanks in advance. But i really don't understand, can you explain for me. Because as i know, qualifier annotation only use when we have more than bean which have same type, but in my application i only declare JavaMailSender?!

Comment: The point is that in your XML file you declared a bean with id `mailSender`. When you use `@Inject` and/or `@Autowired` with no `@Qualifier` spring searches for a bean with id eqauals to the bean name; in your case it searches for a bean with id `javaMailSender`and no `mailSender`